# Feed std::vector<unsigned char> from unsigned char *

Tags: c++, vector

i have write this piece of code:

```
unsigned char *buffer = ...
...
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(buffer,128);
```

This works but i would like to feed the vector after its declaration (suppose the vector is a field of a class)

```
unsigned char *buffer = ...
...
std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
...
vec = vec(buffer,128) ???
```

I do not know what to do on the last line.
The only thing that actually works is to resize the vector then do a memcpy. Is there a better way?

Comment: It may be worth reading through ***[the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)***. That will tell you which functions do what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, with move semantics, you can simply do

```
vec = std::vector<unsigned char>(buffer, buffer + 128);
```

If that ruffles your feathers, you can use `std::copy` together with `std::back_inserter`:

```
vec.reserve(128);
std::copy(buffer, buffer+128, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Another option is to use `vector::assign`.

Comment: Would `vec = std::vector(buffer, 128);` actually work? Which constructor would it call?

Comment: @flatmouse, this is what happens when you copy-paste.

Comment: It's the thought that counts. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since a pointer and an iterator are basically the same thing you can use [`std::vector::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) or [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).  `assign` will set the vector to the range while `insert` will add it to any existing elements in the vector

```
vec.assign(buffer, buffer + size_of_buffer)
//or
vec.insert(vec.end(), buffer, buffer + size_of_buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^ position to insert the elements before
```

---

Also note that

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(buffer,128);
```

Is not a valid constructor call for a `std::vector`  If you are trying to construct the vector directly from the buffer you need

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(buffer, buffer + size_of_buffer);
```